# Make a patch() call from drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class UserProfile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    .......
    .......
    #some codes here
    .......

@csrf_exempt
def change_user_password(self, request):
    #some actions here 
    if(condition):
       UserProfile.patch(request)
    ..........
    return ...
```

Here I've given a sample code, which may not run. But all I need is to make a patch call to `UserProfile` viewset class from the `change_user_password` function

Comment: Why would you do that? You could do it in `UserProfile` viewset..right?

Comment: Your method needs to be indented. Is your code formatting the same in your original code?

Answer (score 1):

You are close you just have to make an object of `UserProfile`, see the edit of sample code:

```
class UserProfile(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    .......
    .......
    #some code here
    .......

def change_user_password(self, request):
    #some action here 
    if(condition):
       user_profile_obj = UserProfile()
       user_profile_obj.patch(request)
    ..........
    return response
```